# jQuery on load animate image from left to right

Tags: jquery

Can some kind person advise how I send this image from the left to the right slowly?
I can see the image and I can click it to go to the url but it doesnt animate, just appears right away?
Thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script>
 $( "#lefttoright" ).animate({opacity: 0.25,    left: "=250",
 height: "toggle"  },  5000, function() {    // Animation complete.
 });}); 
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="lefttoright">    
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="go to link">
    <img src="/images/leftright.png" alt="news" width="150" height="75" /></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the listener in the [DOM ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(function(){

    $( "#lefttoright" ).animate({ opacity: 0.25, left: "250", height: "toggle"  },  5000, function() {    
         // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

The [fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/GmcmG/1/) is here

```
<div id="lefttoright"> <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="go to link">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" alt="news" width="150" height="75" /></a>
</div>

var left = $(window).width() - $('#lefttoright').offset().left;

$("#lefttoright").animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: left,
}, 5000, function () { 
    // Animation complete.
});


#lefttoright {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: brill its doing something, it shows full image and then eats it from the bottom up and its gone, how can I get it to crawl in from left and stop, say after 200px;? thanks

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: Ive no idea how to create a fiddle...sos

Comment: I am not sure of your exact requirements, but something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/GmcmG/

Comment: I get an error on jsfiddle page link for some reason, do I need to create an account for this to work?

Comment: Really? No you dont need an account. Just click on the link, and it should show you the animation.

Comment: mmm it could be a block from my work pc in that case, I will need to look from home...Im after the image coming in from the left side of the screen and floating right until about one third in on the page?

Comment: Agh I see the jsfiddle now on another pc, this is handy and yes thats what Im after thereabouts but the image coming left to right not right to left, I guess I can play with the code you setup now :)